# iOS get message string from one-dimensional image

Tags: ios, barcode

I can get the string message with two-dimensional barcode image and generate the two-dimensional barcode image with input string, but how to get the string message with one-dimensional barcode and how to generate one with a string? The below code is about two-dimensioan barcode:

```
+ (NSString *)decodeImage:(CIImage *)ciImage {
    NSDictionary *options = @{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh};
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:options];
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage];
    for (CIFeature *feature in features) {
        if ([feature isKindOfClass:[CIQRCodeFeature class]]) {
            CIQRCodeFeature *qrFeature = (CIQRCodeFeature *)feature;
            return qrFeature.messageString;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

....
```

How about one-dimensional barcode?

Answer (score 1):

The system you are using does not detect the type of barcodes you are after.

But there is a different system you can use to detect a much greater variety of codes. Look into `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` used in a `AVCaptureSession`.

For a summary of how this works, see https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/barcode-scanning-in-ios-using-avfoundation/